# How to avoid race conditions in reservation-like application?

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I have got inherited reservation-like application in Spring from previous developers. It has not entities like Room, Meeting, etc, but to simplify discussion let's use that terminology.
So, we have Room entity:

```
@Entity
class Room {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other fields
}
```

Also we have Meeting entity, that represents period of time reserved at certain Room:

```
@Entity
class Meeting {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Instant start;
    private Instant end;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    private Room room;

    // other fields
}
```

And in the end RecurrentMeeting entity, that represents recurrent periods of time reserved at certain Room by user-defines rules:

```
@Entity
class RecurrentMeeting {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id")
    private Rule ruleId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    private Room room;

    // other fields
}
```

Users can use this application as following:

Step 1. User calls application with meeting/recurrent meeting request.
Application calculates suitable room (there can be only one or zero rooms by application business logic) and periods of time and returns to user this information.

For example

> 1. Calls for periods of time at 9 March 2021
> 2. Returns: [10AM - 11AM, 5PM - 6PM, 9PM - 10PM]

or

> 1. Calls for periods of time at 9 day of every month starting from March 2021
> 2. Returns: [6AM - 7AM, 4PM - 5PM] - indicates that user can set meeting at that time for every day in rule.

Step 2. User chooses suggested period of time and accept by calling application second time. Application checks again that period of time is correct and room becomes reserved at requested time.

The main problem is case when two users call application in the second step simultaneously (and application decides that they need same room):

1. User 1 calls with suggested period 4AM-5AM (transaction #1)
2. Application checks that 4AM-5AM in suggested room is available (transaction #1)
3. User 2 calls with suggested period 3AM-5AM (transaction #2)
4. Application checks that 3AM-5AM in suggested room is available (transaction #2)
5. transaction #2 commits
6. transaction #1 commits

Now room is reserved at the same time by two users.
So, how we can protect from this case using inherited domain model in database?

I have thought about locking periods of time between steps 1 and 2, but

1. Users can call for long periods of time and can wait before calling step 2 - if we lock periods of times from step 1, we can not use that periods some amount of time.
2. Locking periods of time when two users call step 1 simultaneously is also a problem.

Comment: Create an exclusion constraint in the database that prevents overlapping ranges

Comment: And a link to the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT

Comment: It seems possible when all meetings are in the same table, but I have two tables. Also, ranges for recurrent meetings are stored in different custom table without internal postgres datatypes for ranges